# GCC 4.7.2 on Debian amd64 - built-in atomic increment?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, race-condition

My test source is:

```
volatile int gl = 0;

void * InternalHandler( void * param )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) { ++gl; }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t ths[100] = { 0 };
  for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    pthread_create( &ths[ i ], 0, InternalHandler, 0 );
  }
  for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    pthread_join( ths[ i ], 0 );
  }
  std::cout << gl << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code on my Debian (via VirtualBox), I get exactly 10000000 every time, while it has to be race condition.

uname -a:

```
Linux debian-dev 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

On several other systems I get different results. The race conditions do their job.
But on my virtual Debian it's "implicit atomic". Why could it be?

Comment: Your code has UB. Use `std::atomic<int>`. (The hardware "add 1" instruction isn't atomic by default, not on any reasonable system. On x86 it needs a lock prefix, which the compiler doesn't emit unless you use atomic types or operations.)

Comment: I'm not trying to PREVENT race condition. I'm trying to MAKE race condition.

Comment: The race condition makes it UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There most definitely is a data race.

You probably don't see it because your virtual machine is only using a single core; and is running on an architecture which performs the increment using a single CPU instruction (meaning that a task switch can't happen in the middle of it).

If you run it on a multi-core machine, or an architecture (such as ARM) that doesn't have CPU instructions for directly modifying values in memory, then you should see inconsistent results as expected.

For example, if I run it on my 8-core machine I get:

```
$ ./a.out 
1666121
$ ./a.out 
1632606
```

while constraining it to a single core gives

```
$ taskset -c 0 ./a.out 
10000000
$ taskset -c 0 ./a.out
10000000
```

You can fix the data race by using `std::atomic<int>`. If C++11 is not available, you could use platform-specific atomic operations such as GCC's [`__sync_fetch_and_add`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html), or (if the performance impact is acceptable) guard the variable with a mutex.

Comment: That's it! Virtual machine used only single core.